# Don't understand the key binding for `auto-yasnippet`

Tags: key-bindings, yasnippet

I am looking to use `auto-yasnippet` but I don't understand the key bindings they are suggesting such as `H-w` and `H-y`. I haven't seen any key binding that starts with `H` so I am not sure what that is. I tried looking at the official documentation for emacs key binding and didn't see any that started with `H` so I figured I would ask here.

https://github.com/abo-abo/auto-yasnippet

Comment: `H` stands for Hyper, more details are here http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was probably going to be the Windows key but I didn't know how to change it. Though unfortunately that tutorial didn't work for me on Windows 10. I'll just remap the bindings. Thank you though.